# Get logs of a previous version of linux-next

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

I am working on [git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git). According to my understanding, it rebases every day to mainline kernel branch and merges all the branches. So, the logs of a previous linux-next version cannot be seen in the current version released. Is there a way to get the logs of the previous versions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each linux-next release is tagged like next-YYYYMMDD (so today's will be next-20190228).  The last three month's worth of releases are kept in the linux-next tree you cite above and all the rest are archived in the linux-next-history tree (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next-history.git).